# Change DateFormat for an entire Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, date

I Would like to change all Displayed dateformats in my angular project to 1 unified date format.
One solution would be to use the Date pipe provided with a saved constant, and I am not against this solution, but it would be very cool if there was a way to just universeally change the dateformat of all displayed dates in my project in one place, so that all the displayed dates do not require a datepipe.

I appreciate the time you spend answering this question!

Comment: I can't see a way of doing this without using a pipe. You can create your own custom pipe in order to avoid juggling a constant around the app.

Comment: I agree with Will. Unless you are already using a custom pipe for displaying dates then there isn't a way to do this. Since the date properties themselves aren't values you want to manipulate, only the visual representation of them are.

I will leave you with my experience on using the datePipe in a project with multiple languages, stick with the predefined format options `https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options`. These provide locale based datetime formats out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I remember achieving this with the following approach.

Define the application date format in a `constants.ts` file:

```
  APP_DATE_FORMATS: {
    parse: {
      dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    },
    display: {
      dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
      monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
      dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
      monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
    },
  }
```

Import required dependencies from Angular and define them in your module as follows (omit the first line if you're not using Angular Material UI library):

```
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
```

Within the `@NgModule` section, include these dependencies as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS] },
    { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: constants.APP_DATE_FORMATS }
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

All of your components will adapt the date format you defined in your constants file.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, however it doesn't seem to function 

`export const MY_MAT_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a'
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
    }
};`

and in my app.module.ts providers:

Comment: @NobiliChili Is `@angular/material-moment-adapter` in your package.json file? If not, you should install this package.